Setting min and max values for gradient of vector layer style larger than the layer's data in QGIS
I am working on a project with climate projections data. I need to keep the same layer style for different layers, in order to allow the comparison in increase or decrease of the variables' values (mean temperature, precipitation, etc).
Simplified example:

Vector layer 1: mean temperature increase projection in the short term (1921-1940).
Vector layer 2: mean temperature increase projection in the mid-term (1941-1960).
Vector layer 3: mean temperature increase projection in the long term (1981-2100).

The data ranges for each layer in this example are:

VL1: [0.5; 1.2]
VL2: [0.8; 2.4]
VL3: [2.2; 4.5]

The idea is to have a gradient-like style that covers the data range [0.5; 4.5]. Inputting manually each category would mean too much time since the desired number of classes is around 100, and also considering the number of variables, that are more than 30.
Is there a compliment or workflow alternative to set a desired data range for a layer style, which defines the values of a predefined color ramp?
With raster data is possible to do so, it would be useful to do the same with vector data.
I am using QGIS 3.34 (Win)

You can merge your layers, or create a fake layer with your overall min & max values, then create the desired style. Or manually create the color ramp intervals with the desired min & max boundaries. The apply (copy paste) this style to your individual VL1, 2 3 layers.

I see now what you meant about "fake layer", as a layer without geometry, and setting the values through the attribute table, it works. Thank you.

yes, without geometries, or with at least 2 geometries having the min & max values. Then to get rid of this temporary layer. The gradients style don't update themselves automatically on the min/max values as far as I know (opposite to raster). So whether using this suggestion or the one in the answer, once you have made your Style with the desired min & max, you are good to apply it to any layer you wish.

If you add a value in your layers with no geometry (trough the attribute table) with the min and max value, the symbology will take them into account.
