Layer style autoupdates to match data range in QGIS
I am copying and pasting the style from one vector layer to another (ctually, the layers are linked to the same shapefile, but different fields are represented), and after a while -few seconds or less- the style autoupdates with new categories, matching the range of the new layer. I would like to keep the same categories in order to make both layers comparable. It happens also when opening the layer properties and modifying the "value" (field to represent), even with autoupdate turned off. The map representation does not update, but the categories change automatically to match the new range.
The data is in vector format and is about several climate variables shown in different scenarios.
Any idea about why this could be happening or workaround alternatives would be of great help. I am using QGIS 3.34 (win).

Are you using the categorized or graduated style?

I am using Graduated style with fixed interval. Curiously by using this method (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/488383/setting-min-and-max-values-for-gradient-of-vector-layer-style-larger-than-the-la?noredirect=1#comment796471_488383) it doesn't happen, so I could go on with my task. But why it happens remains not clear

To avoid having the classes being recomputed, you can switch from graduated to rule based.
On the source layer, configure the graduated as you wish, then change the style to rule based. The classes from graduated are automatically transformed into rules.
You can now copy/paste this style to other layers.
